# Installing RHEL 7 and can't make partition while on dual boot

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning

I've problem while installing RHEL 7 with dual boot. Windows 8.1 pro already installed and try to install RHEL 7 but while on partition segment I can't see unallocated space which was more than 100GB, only ntfs are shown. At bottom of left corner it shown 20000 free space. So, how and where did I can see those unallocated space and make partition.

I'm fresher in this field, please help me out.

Thank you!

Bipin Singh